# Two figures side by side with two captions and alphanumeric counting

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, subfloats

How can I have two figure side by side with two captions and in the floating format, like

```
fig. 10A. some caption                fig. 10B. some caption
```

Comment: Hi! Have you seen the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig), or the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) packages?

Comment: @Ruben I've first thought it's a duplicate, but it's not. That one asks for numbering like `Fig 10, Fig 11`, this one wants `Fig 10a, Fig 10b`.

Comment: @tohecz you are totally right. And you alredy suggested the use of `subfig`. Why not adding it as an answer?

Comment: @Ruben Because I know that the question _was_ asked before, I just can't find it. Moreover, I've never used `subfig` myself, so I'm just leaving it to someone else ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} %ifpdf
\makeatletter
  \def\thesubfigure{Fig. \@arabic\c@figure\Alph{subfigure}.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Some caption]{\rule{.45\textwidth}{3cm}} %replace \rule... with \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{picname}
\hspace{2em}
\subfloat[Some other caption]{\rule{.45\textwidth}{3cm}} %idem
%\caption{Some caption title}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: subcap_demo]